# Possible? Internet connected VST audio plugin placed on midi/audio tracks on DAWs, e.g. Ableton, Logic, etc

Tags: audio, vst

Is this possible to create?

Requirements

1. VST can **send** messages to a webserver
2. VST can **receive** messages from a webserver
3. VST can **automatically** receive/send messages to/from the webserver, e.g. in the background, without the user having to open the plugin window, pressing a button etc.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  You can build a VST to do most anything you want.

Comment: @Brad. Thanks! Even send/receive audio files to/from webserver?

Comment: Sure, why not?  It's your code, you can do what you like!

Comment: @Brad haha thanks. I will never let anybody tell me what I can or can't do with my code 

Comment: @Brad  another question I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70357690/possible-vst-audio-plugin-evaluate-sound-note-pattern-similarity-of-a-track-o